Note briefly visible on train window in a (possibly) Hitchcock movie
Years ago in a B&W, possibly Hitchcock movie, there was a scene where the characters sat in a dining car looking out the window. A worker had tossed a container of trash off the moving train and for a second a scrap of paper blew against the window with critical notes on it, just briefly visible. I think the scene was in Europe but not "Strangers on a Train". What was on the paper was important to the plot!

You're thinking of a memorable moment in Hitchcock's The Lady Vanishes from 1938.

After the train has restarted, and under the threat of being put off the train at the next stop, Iris returns to her compartment alone. Meanwhile, some rubbish has been thrown out of the dining car and a gaudy tea label for Harriman's Herbal sticks briefly to the window in front of Gilbert. This is enough to make him believe Iris [about the old lady vanishing who drank the tea with her] and he rushes back to her.

Here's the trailer and the relevant pic:

